# Jenkins Job Fails After One Finding By Sonatype

Tags: sonatype

So we use Sonatype Nexus Repo Manager and their IQ server offering also using Jenkins.

When a build is kicked off in Jenkins and it comes across a component that fails and gets quarantined the build will just fail and then have to go look as to why it's failing and take appropriate action depending what is found. Then you run the build again and it'll find the next component inline that fails and so on and so on.

I was wondering has anyone setup a way for the jenkins job/build to continue after the first component gets quarantined as to get all the components rather than find one run the job again find another run the job again?

I talked with our Sonatype Rep and he said there isn't away and unfortunately this is just how it works. Which I find crap because I feel like this would be pissing off a lot more people if this truly is how it works.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Dev team tried to find a way to handle the error to continue but so far no luck.